# cakephp HABTM association

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-model

Hi I have a site develop in cakephp.
I have two tables:
Ingredient 
Property

The relation between the tables is HasAndBelongsToMany(HABTM).
This is my model:

```
class Ingredient extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Ingredient';
    public $useTable = 'ingredients';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Property' => array (
            'className'             => 'Property',
            'joinTable'             => 'ingredients_properties',
            'foreignKey'            => 'ingredient_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'property_id',
            'unique'                => false
        )
    );

}

class Property extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'Property'; 
        public $useTable = 'properties';

}
```

Into my IngredientController I have to add a new Property I have tried in this mode:

```
$this->Ingredient->Property->create();
                $this->Ingredient->Property->set('user_id',$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
                $this->Ingredient->Property->set('ingredient_id',$ing['IngredientAlias']['ingredient_id']);
                if ($this->Ingredient->Property->save($this->request->data)){
                    $this->set('flash_element','success');
                    $this->Session->setFlash ('Ingrediente modificato con successo.');
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'edit',$alias));
                }
                else{
                    $this->set('flash_element','error');
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Errore di salvataggio activity');
                }
```

Into the database insert a new record but If I want that is relation between the ingredients with insert a record in ingredients_properties(table of join), how can I do that? In this mode is like Ingredients hasMany Properties but is not correct.
How can I solve it?
Or I have to create the record into ingredients_properties manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that:

```
class Ingredient extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Ingredient';
    public $useTable = 'ingredients';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Property' => array (
            'className'             => 'Property',
            'joinTable'             => 'ingredients_properties',
            'foreignKey'            => 'ingredient_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'property_id',
            'unique'                => false
        )
    );

}

class Property extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'Property'; 
        public $useTable = 'properties';
        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Ingredient' => array (
            'className'             => 'Ingredient',
            'joinTable'             => 'ingredients_properties',
            'foreignKey'            => 'property_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'unique'                => false
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: If the tables `ingredients` and `properties` are in different databases, does it matter which database the join table is in? How do I specify where the join table is located or is cake smart enough to check both databases?

Comment: I think that you have to make manually this relation if you have tables in different database. read this article about it: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/04/04/cakephp-how-to-sav-habtm-data-with-tables-in-different-databases/ @Scott

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the following link to achieve the same:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Comment: I have solved with this link because the error is in the property model I have to insert the HABTM relations too